# Firestore Transaction is triggered multiple time when reading the data from multiple documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore Transaction to read multiple documents data. I used transaction before to write multiple documents at once and it is working okay but when I am trying to read the data, the transaction function call itself multiple times and in the end it tells me transaction timeout on OnFailureListener. I have attached the code below and it would be great if someone tell me what is the issue here.

```
private void getFireBaseData(final String userType, String typeID) {
        final DocumentReference profileRef = fireStoreDb.collection("users").document(AppValues.userId);
        final DocumentReference aboutMeRef = fireStoreDb.collection(AppValues.userId).document("aboutMe");

        final DocumentReference typeRef = fireStoreDb.collection(AppValues.userType + "s").document(typeID);

        fireStoreDb.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
                Log.e(TAG, "Transaction started!");
                    DocumentSnapshot profileSnapshot = transaction.get(profileRef);
                    DocumentSnapshot aboutMeSnapshot = transaction.get(aboutMeRef);
                    DocumentSnapshot typeSnapshot = transaction.get(typeRef);

                    AppValues.profile = profileSnapshot.toObject(Profile.class);
                    AppValues.aboutMeDetails = aboutMeSnapshot.toObject(AboutMeDetails.class);

                    if (userType.equals("helper")) {
                        AppValues.helper = typeSnapshot.toObject(Helper.class);
                    } else if (userType.equals("needer")) {
                        AppValues.needer = typeSnapshot.toObject(Needer.class);
                    }

                    callNavigationActivity();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Transaction success!");

                return null;
            }

        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // callNavigationActivity();
                Log.e(TAG, "Transaction success complete!");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Transaction Failure! " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only supposed to use a transaction if you intend to make changes to all the documents you read.  Also, you can expect that a transaction handler may be run multiple times.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by
>   any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().
>   In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire
>   transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and
>   another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore
>   retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction
>   runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

(You're also hiding some functionality behind callNavigationActivity(). That could be its own problem.  Seems like you probably don't want to do that either from within a transaction.)

If you don't need to update the documents you read, don't use a transaction.